# "step" not ending program at the end of program, but it ending it after 5 more "step"

Tags: c, gdb

I am using Windows 10. I wrote a HelloWorld program in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled this with cmd with the following command

```
gcc -g -o HelloWorld HelloWorld.c
```

In gdb, I write `start`. And I typed `step` quite a few times. At some point it prints

```
(gdb) step
7       }
```

Then I typed `step` again. It prints

```
(gdb) step
__tmainCRTStartup () at C:/crossdev/src/mingw-w64-v4-git/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:334
334     C:/crossdev/src/mingw-w64-v4-git/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c: No such file or directory.
```

After another step it prints

```
332     in C:/crossdev/src/mingw-w64-v4-git/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c
```

After that it prints above line every time I wrote `step`. And eventually sometime it printed

```
[Thread 1952.0x1628 exited with code 0]
[Inferior 1 (process 1952) exited normally]
```

I want to know, what I have done wrong that causes the problem.

Comment: Most likely, you have done nothing wrong, it's your environment causing those extra "step"s.

Comment: Your `main` is called by some [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) and your debugger is stepping into it

Comment: Or more precisely, *back to it* after stepping out of the previous call.

Comment: (FYI, you can just do `s` instead of `step`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> “step” not ending program at the end of program

The problem is that your notion of where your program begins and ends is quite wrong: your program executes 100s or 1000s of instructions before it reaches `main`, and 100s or 1000s more after `main` returns.

These instructions are part of C runtime startup and shutdown. Usually you are not interested in debugging there, but developers of the C runtime do need to debug it, and the debugger doesn't know whether you want to or not.

> Can you tell me how i can tell gdb to debug only my code.

GDB *doesn't know* which code is your own, and which isn't (and I don't believe there is a way to tell it).

If you don't want to debug past the end of `main`, then don't ask GDB to do so: once you reach the end of "your code", use `continue` instead of `step`.

Comment: Can you tell me how i can tell gdb to debug only my code.